Invalid XSD schema using libxmljs with NodeJS with flattened XSD
I want to validate an XML document against an XSD schema. I'm using libxmljs 0.33 with NodeJS 18.
I keep receiving this error:
Error: Invalid XSD schema
    at createPDF (/root/workspace/app/apps/docapi/src/modules/generator/src/de/fwht-recovery-dip/index.ts:20:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/root/workspace/app/apps/docapi/src/modules/generator/test/de.fwht-recovery-dip.test.ts:6:31)
    at Promise.then.completed (/root/workspace/app/node_modules/jest-circus/build/utils.js:298:28)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at callAsyncCircusFn (/root/workspace/app/node_modules/jest-circus/build/utils.js:231:10)
    at _callCircusTest (/root/workspace/app/node_modules/jest-circus/build/run.js:316:40)
    at _runTest (/root/workspace/app/node_modules/jest-circus/build/run.js:252:3)
    at _runTestsForDescribeBlock (/root/workspace/app/node_modules/jest-circus/build/run.js:126:9)
    at _runTestsForDescribeBlock (/root/workspace/app/node_modules/jest-circus/build/run.js:121:9)
    at run (/root/workspace/app/node_modules/jest-circus/build/run.js:71:3)
    at runAndTransformResultsToJestFormat (/root/workspace/app/node_modules/jest-circus/build/legacy-code-todo-rewrite/jestAdapterInit.js:122:21)
    at jestAdapter (/root/workspace/app/node_modules/jest-circus/build/legacy-code-todo-rewrite/jestAdapter.js:79:19)
    at runTestInternal (/root/workspace/app/node_modules/jest-runner/build/runTest.js:367:16)
    at runTest (/root/workspace/app/node_modules/jest-runner/build/runTest.js:444:34)

This is the code I'm running to receive this error:
  const schemasRoot = path.join(__dirname, 'schemas');

  const xsdSchema = fs.readFileSync(path.join(schemasRoot, 'dip_flattened.xsd'), 'utf-8');
  const xmlDocument = fs.readFileSync(path.join(schemasRoot, 'schema-test.xml'), 'utf-8');

  const schema = libxml.parseXmlString(xsdSchema);
  const document = libxml.parseXmlString(xmlDocument);
  console.log(schema.validate(document));

I tried using the same XSD in Oxygen XML and it works fine.
I looked up the error and came across this issue. It mentioned issues regarding importing/including other schemas. I eliminated that problem completely by flattening the XSD files into one giant file. So it couldn't be that.
This Gist contains the XML and XSD schema. Thanks

the error stack seems to be coming from jest-circus, a test runner.. perhaps it needs to be reconfigured..

@traynor that's because I'm calling it from a test file, same error when i run using ts-node

Flattening a schema isn't possible if there is more than one target namespace: perhaps you generated an invalid schema. Without seeing the schema it is complaining about, it's impossible to tell.

@MichaelKay I encountered that issue and fixed it, it's not the one causing it.
For now i'm using a command line tool xmllint and calling it using child_process.exec, I hate it but I can't get stuck on this forever.

You're trying to parse from a string, which means the base URI won't be known, which means it won't be possible to resolve any relative URIs in href attributes. Check whether the API allows you to parse from a filename or URI, or to supply a base URI when parsing from a string.

@MichaelKay I tried it an absolute path as well as with a baseUrl. Nothing worked.

"Nothing worked" is never a good way of approaching things. Identity one thing that didn't work, and post enough information so that other people can reproduce the problem.

@MichaelKay Thank you for the help, I figured it out it was a dumb mistake by me posted it as an answer and accepted. Thanks!

The mistake in my code is quite dumb and trivial, you should use the call validate method on the XML you want to validate rather than on the schema, the schema should be the parameter.
Sorry for the trouble.
It should be this way console.log(schema.validate(document));
